# How to check if files are served from tmpfs memory cache or disk cache

Tags: linux, codeigniter, nginx, caching

I have a web application and the details are shared below. I have enabled page caching and database caching for a CodeIgniter 3.1x web application. 
Page cache is stored in `app_dir/application/cache`.
Database cache is stored in `app_dir/application/db_cache`.

While I can see an improvement in performance after enabling page and database caching, I decided to mount the page cache directory and database cache directory hoping to improve the performance.

1. How do I find out if `Nginx` is serving the request from the cache directories on disk or the cache directories mounted in memory.
2. My cache directories will be updated every thirty minutes. Will I have to mount the directories manually after every update or will Linux mount it automatically?
3. How do I ensure requests are served from memory mounted cache directories and not from the local file system?

Setup details:

1. Ubuntu 18x
2. Nginx v.1.14
3. CodeIgniter

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this header?

```
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
```

Look at https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/ on the "Can the NGINX Cache Be Instrumented?"

Comment: Hi, @Horacio. I haven't explored caching at NGinx level. All caching is done at application level by Codeigniter. My views are generated and cached by CodeIgniter. With proxy_cache_path, will I be adding another layer of caching at the webserver level with NGinx? What happens when CodeIgniter refreshes the view cache every 30 minutes? Will NGinx automatically refresh the entire cache in memory or will I have to set 'inactive' to 30 minutes? I have never explored caching with NGinx as I am relatively new to it.